# Can i write custom bulk action for my custom fields in wordpress? if yes, what are the ways to do that?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am working on wordpress website where i am generating Landing Pages dynamically. I have used custom fields such as price, background image etc. on these landing pages. Now i want to create a custom bulk action for those pages where I can update price field for all the landing pages at once. Now how do i create bulk action for that.

Comment: Have you done any research? Made any code / attempts to achieve this? If so please include them in your question

Comment: No. I didn't wrote any code for bulk action yet. I am looking for a proper way to that, so i have done some research. I found that there is a plugin called custom bulk action (https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-bulk-actions/). But its not compatible with WP version i am using. Updating my WP version might be risky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a the code to begin with :

```
add_action('admin_footer-edit.php', 'custom_bulk_admin_footer');
 function custom_bulk_admin_footer() {

  global $post_type;

  if($post_type == 'post') {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('<option>').val('edit_custom_field...').text('<?php _e('Update custo....')?>').appendTo("select[name='udpate...action1']");
        jQuery('<option>').val('edit_custom_field...').text('<?php _e('Update custo....')?>').appendTo("select[name='udpate...action2']");
      });
    </script>
    <?php
  }
}



add_action('load-edit.php', 'custom_bulk_action');

function custom_bulk_action() {

  // ...

  // 1. get the action
  $wp_list_table = _get_list_table('WP_Posts_List_Table');
  $action = $wp_list_table->current_action();

  // ...

  // 2. security check
  check_admin_referer('bulk-posts');

  // ...

  switch($action) {
    // 3. Perform the action
    case 'export':
      // if we set up user permissions/capabilities, the code might look like:
      //if ( !current_user_can($post_type_object->cap->export_post, $post_id) )
      //  pp_die( __('You are not allowed to export this post.') );

      $exported = 0;

      foreach( $post_ids as $post_id ) {
        if ( !$this->perform_export($post_id) )
          wp_die( __('Error exporting post.') );
        $exported++;
      }

      // build the redirect url
      $sendback = add_query_arg( array('exported' => $exported, 'ids' => join(',', $post_ids) ), $sendback );

    break;
    default: return;
  }

  // ...

  // 4. Redirect client
  wp_redirect($sendback);

  exit();
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks alot. I will explore this  code. Seems like it will work for me.

Comment: how can I create export bulk for custom post type?